# Выделить несколько элементов с похожими id

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Можно ли выделить несколько id у которых в название есть общее соотвествие значений, например в середине полного названия id?
например:

```
id="aya"
id="byb"
id="cyc"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно через *CSS*

```css
[id*="yo"] {
  border: 5px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="yo">tet1</div>
<div id="12yo234">tet2</div>
<div id="y1o">tet3</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо. По моему и в js работает.

Comment: ну обычно да. они по селекторам css всегда работают, что чистый js что jquery

Comment: а можно сделать исключение, например для <div id="12yo234">tet2</div>